# Use result of binary expression as an instant vector

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a binary expression like the following:

```
up{instance=~"^.*:.*"} unless up{instance=~"^.*:10000$"}
```

It's just an example. I know that I could write regular expression so that it'll be just one. But it's a simplified example. Real dataset contains lot of series out of which I need to extract a subset and then filter out certain items.

I need to use the result of this expression (instant vector, right?) as one would use a typical instant vector - grab a range and feed to something like `rate` function for example. And it turns out that it's either not possible or I misunderstand some fundamental concept about PromQL.

How would one take a rate of the result of this expression?

**UPDATE:**

The following works:

```
rate(up{instance=~"^.*:.*"}[5m]) unless rate(up{instance=~"^.*:10000$"}[5m])
```

However, I was looking for a way to filter first and rate second, since otherwise a lot of rate processing will be done on series that will simply be dropped later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prometheus allows specifying multiple filters for the same label in a single series selector, then apply `rate` function to it - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72926966/274937) for details.

Prometheus allows passing arbitrary query results to functions, which accept e.g. `range vectors`, by using [subqueries](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/). For example, the following query would calculate arbitrary query `q` with 30-seconds interval between calculated points and then apply `rate` with 5 minutes lookbehind window over the calculated results:

```
rate((q)[5m:30s])
```

In general subqueries aren't recommended to use because they are hard to construct properly and because they may take too much cpu and memory to execute when improperly constructed.