# How to filter out certain series from a subset of timeseries?

Tags: prometheus, promql

We have a lot of series out of which I need to extract a subset and then filter out certain ones. How does one do it in PromQL. Would be great to be able to do it with just one regular expression, but I can't think of any, especially in such limited regex subset, without lookaheads (or something).

I ended up with something like this (real regex is obviously much more complicated):

```
up{instance=~"^.*:.*"} unless up{instance=~"^.*:10000$"}
```

Is this how it is done or is there a better best practice?

Comment: Nah, you pretty much covered it. The only thing that could possibly help is the negative match. E.g. `up{instance!~"some_garbage.*"}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PromQL allows specifying multiple filters for the same label in a single [time series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors). For example, the following query would find `up` series matching `{instance=~"^.*:.*"}` and simultaneously not matching `{instance=~"^.*:10000$"}`:

```
up{instance=~"^.*:.*", instance!~"^.*:10000$"}
```

Note that Prometheus automatically adds `^` and `$` anchors to the beginning and the end of regexps, so the query can be simplified to:

```
up{instance=~".*:.*", instance!~".*:10000"}
```